# Как сделать чтобы CanExecute c MVVM toolkit работала постоянно в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-commands, wpf-toolkit

Учу MVVM и решил использовать MVVM Toolkit. Когда присваиваю команде CanExecute он срабатывает только при запуске программы, но CanExecute больше не срабатывает и не реагирует на изменение свойств.
Хочу узнать как правильно реализовать команду.

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string login;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string password;


    [RelayCommand(CanExecute =nameof(CanSignIn))]
    private async Task SignIn()
    {

        if (_userService.Authorization(login, password) == true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Произошел вход в аккаунт");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Неверные входные данные");
        }
    }


    private bool CanSignIn()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(login) == true || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: [Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand#:~:text=For%20instance%2C%20this%20is%20how%20a%20command%20can%20be%20bound%20to%20a%20property%20to%20control%20its%20state%3A), внимание на `[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(GreetUserCommand))]`. P.S. Поля по типу `public string login;` обычно делают приватными.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь, помогло